# Task Manager not opening from Control+Alt+Delete (GPO set to disallowed)

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, hotkeys

I'm in the process of trying to lock down a computer and was having an issue with task manager not opening from the Windows Security screen. I had the Task Manager executable white-listed in the GPO settings so I could open it from everywhere but the Control+Alt+Delete Screen. Logoff and the other options worked fine.

I checked the event viewer and saw that LaunchTM.exe was being blocked. White-listed it and everything is working as intended now. So just in case someone else has the same issue in the future, here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GPO editor --- User Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Software Restriction Policies\Additional Rules

Create a new path rule to  - C:\Windows\System32\LaunchTM.exe
and set to unrestricted